# Ignoring malformed utf8 in python3

Tags: python, lxml

I have a script to convert xml to text (extract document content sans xml tags) that needs to deal with corrupt xml files.

The corruption comes from a partially decoded zip file, so there may be a utf8 character that got truncated. `lxml` throws an error when encountering the last few bytes.

The data is coming from `stdin` or a file, if that makes a difference.

How can I 'sanitize' any malformed trailing bytes before using lxml, or selectively just ignore this specific error?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
def xml2text(xml):
    """
    A string representing the textual content of this run, with content
    child elements like ``<w:tab/>`` translated to their Python
    equivalent.
    Adapted from: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/
    """
    text = u''
    parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    root = lxml.etree.parse(xml, parser)
    for child in root.iter():
        if child.tag == qn('w:t'):
            t_text = child.text
            text += t_text if t_text is not None else ''
        elif child.tag == qn('w:tab'):
            text += '\t'
        elif child.tag in (qn('w:br'), qn('w:cr')):
            text += '\n'
        elif child.tag == qn("w:p"):
            text += '\n\n'
    return text


def process(docx):
    text = u''
    text += xml2text(docx)

    return text.strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = process_args()
    if args.docx is None:
        text = process(sys.stdin)
    else:
        text = process(args.docx)
    sys.stdout.write(text)
```

Comment: Without seeing your overall logic, what more can we say than "sounds like a good idea"? Recovering from errors within an XML document is nontrivial, though; you end up losing the close tags on any open tags.

Comment: *I have a script* and *lxml throws an error when encountering the last few bytes.* - Please share your code and errors.

Comment: @tripleee. It's a given that closing tags may be missing. I am trying to extract as much text content (between tags) as possible. What do you mean by "sounds like a good idea?" - I don't know *how* to ignore utf-8 errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `errors` parameter when decoding UTF-8 to a string, which allows you to replace or remove the incomplete characters.

```
>>> data = "蛇".encode("utf-8")
>>> data
b'\xe8\x9b\x87'
>>> data[:-1].decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
'�'
>>> data[:-1].decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
''
```

So you could do that before passing the data to lxml.

You can also specify this parameter when creating a `TextIOWrapper` (wrapping it around the original binary file object) in case you have a large XML document and want to process it as a stream without reading it all into memory at once.

In the context of the updated question:

```
def process(stream):
    wrapped_stream = TextIOWrapper(stream, errors="replace")
    text = xml2text(wrapped_stream)
    return text.strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = process_args()
    if args.docx is None:
        text = process(sys.stdin.buffer)
    else:
        with open(args.docx, "rb") as f:
            text = process(f)
    sys.stdout.write(text)
```

See docs for the codecs and io modules:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: But of course, this will retrieve malformed XML unless you are extremely lucky.

Comment: True. But maybe the invalid UTF-8 data is embedded in a valid XML document in this particular case. Or maybe the XML is parsed using a streaming parser, so unclosed elements can be ignored. The question did say that the files are corrupt but need to be dealt with anyway.